# See sql queries in django-rest

Tags: sql, django-rest-framework

How to see SQL queries in django rest framework?

I want "see" this queries. Reading around internet, I found some issues with django-debug-toolbar... Is there a way wihout use django-toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say u have a following orm :

```
users = User.objects.all()
```

Then u can use the debugger or python shell to see the query as follows :

```
print(users.query)
```